# How can I find the maximum number of different sized (given range) spheres fitting inside a cube?

Tags: packing-problem

I have spheres of diameter d1, d2, d3 and d4. I have a cube of dimension L. How can I find the numbers of different sized spheres to have a densest possible packing? I have looked below in [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePacking.html) but that is for uniform size (just one size actually)

Comment: Why do you think there is a (finite) maximal number? Given any packing of  finite number of spheres, there is always space for one more (sufficiently small) sphere.

Comment: I'm looking for a given range of sizes. I know there could be many possible spaces if we use smaller sized particles.